# Postgres - Combine COUNTS and GROUP BY in results table

Tags: sql, postgresql

https://dbfiddle.uk/z01O9eNR

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fruit_name VARCHAR,
    purchase_date DATE
);
```

The following is data in the table:

```
+------------------+
| Results Table 1a |
+----+------------+---------------+
| id | fruit_name | purchase_date |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | apple      |   2021-02-02  |
|  2 | pear       |   2021-02-02  |
|  3 | orange     |   2021-02-02  |
|  4 | apple      |   2021-02-02  |
|  5 | grapes     |   2021-02-04  |
|  6 | grapes     |   2021-02-05  |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

How can I create a `SELECT` statement that not only returns the contents of the table like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits;
```

But also gives me an additional column that tells me *how many purchases were made the same date*. I want a results table that looks like this:

```
+------------------+
| Results Table 1b |
+----+------------+---------------+--------------------+
| id | fruit_name | purchase_date | same_day_purchases |
+----+------------+---------------+--------------------+
|  1 | apple      |   2021-02-02  |                  4 |
|  2 | pear       |   2021-02-02  |                  4 |
|  3 | orange     |   2021-02-02  |                  4 |
|  4 | apple      |   2021-02-02  |                  4 |
|  5 | grapes     |   2021-02-04  |                  1 |
|  6 | grapes     |   2021-02-05  |                  1 |
+----+------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Example: there were 4 purchases made on `2021-02-02` so for each `purchase_date` of that date, the `same_day_purchases` should be 4.

I can create a separate statement using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT purchase_date, COUNT(*) AS same_date_purchases
FROM fruits
GROUP BY purchase_date;
```

But I'm looking for a way to make a statement enables the results table of `Results Table 1b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `COUNT` window function as the following:

```
SELECT id, fruit_name, purchase_date,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_date) AS same_date_purchases
FROM fruits
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5pMuM_9E).